Why are my search results not shown in the view in VS Code?
After entering a search query in the search panel in VS code, no results are shown. I can only select "Open in Editor" to show all results.

How can I get the search results to show in the view again, like in this example?

This is something that always worked, but suddenly broke.
Version: 1.94.2 (user setup)
Commit: 384ff7382de624fb94dbaf6da11977bba1ecd427
Electron: 30.5.1
ElectronBuildld: 10262041
Chromium: 124.0.6367.243
Node.js: 20.16.0
V8: 12.4.254.20-electron.O
OS: Windows NT x64 10.0.19045


Why the downvote?

It was fixed after a reboot of my laptop.
